# Circular network with central node using R

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph, correlation

I want to make a network-like the figure below, based on a correlation matrix (c). Where, edge type, size and color is based on strength of [correlation](/questions/tagged/correlation) (we can make three distinctions, high positive, high negative and one in between) and the pie within each node (red and green color) based on a two (NP) column vector (on column with total positive correlation for a variable and other with negative correlation).

Some random variables

```
DD<- matrix(NA, 1000, 6)

for (i in 1:6){
    DD[,i]=runif(1000)
}
```

Their correlation and sums

```
C=cor(DD)

diag(C)<- 0

NP<- matrix(NA, 6, 2)

NP[,1]<-rowSums(C < 0,na.rm=TRUE)
NP[,2]<-rowSums(C > 0,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: please add some data, so that your problem can be reproduced by other users here. Check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example]

Comment: I thought it would be a simple solution but it is taking too much time.